# How to limit pushing operation to allow only commits that are signed with GPG in github

Tags: git, github, githooks, git-push

I've a Github repository we share for our development. To ensure the integrity we decided to sign our commits and tags with GPG.

Now, how do I prevent developers from pushing unsigned commits to our repository in Github and also white-list GPG public keys to allow pushing commits singed with white-listed public keys

I checked out some pre-pushing hooks but didn't work out the way I described above and here it is.

```
remote="$1"
url="$2"

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

IFS=' '
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$local_sha" = $z40 ]
    then
    # Handle delete
    else
    if [ "$remote_sha" = $z40 ]
    then
        # New branch, examine all commits
        range="$local_sha"
    else
        # Update to existing branch, examine new commits
        range="$remote_sha..$local_sha"
    fi

    # Check for WIP commit
    commit=`git rev-list -n 1 --grep '^WIP' "$range"`
    if [ -n "$commit" ]
    then
        echo "Found WIP commit in $local_ref, not pushing"
        exit 1
     fi
    fi
 done
exit 0
```

How can I get this done? Any notion or examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're checking for any commit `git log --grep '^WIP'` would find. You appear to be asking to check whether any commit lacks a GPG signature—so you will need to write a test for "has or lacks GPG signature". Then you may also need to decide whether you want to check, if there *is* a signature, whether it is valid. But StackOverflow is not a "write code for me" service...

Comment: You could allow pushing the commits but add a Status Check that requires them to be signed before merging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are on GitHub Enterprise and trying to [create a pre-receive hook script](https://help.github.com/enterprise/admin/guides/developer-workflow/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script/) that rejects any unsigned commits - correct?  If so, here is [an open source GPG script](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/block_unsigned_commits.sh) from GitHub.  If you are on GitHub.com, please note they do not support pre-receive hooks and instead you would want to set up a [protected branch with required status check](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks) to reject unsigned work.

As for setting up keys, have you checked out [this article](https://help.github.com/enterprise/user/articles/signing-commits-with-gpg/)?